# Adding a label to a JComboBox and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

Hi I am having trouble adding labels to my combo box and textfield.It compiles fine but only shows the boxes but without labels.

```
import javax.swing. *;
import java.awt.event. *;   
import java.awt.FlowLayout;        

public class AreaFrame2  
{  

   public static void main(String[]args)  
   { 

      //Create array containing shapes  
      String[] shapes ={"(no shape selected)","Circle","Equilateral Triangle","Square"};  

      //Use combobox to create drop down menu
      JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox(shapes);
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(); 
      JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Select shape:");
      panel1.add(label1);
      comboBox.add(panel1);
      JButton button = new JButton("GO");
      JTextField text = new JTextField(20);

      //Create a JFrame that will be use to put JComboBox into it 
      JFrame frame=new JFrame("Area Calculator Window");  
      frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //set layout
      frame.add(comboBox);//add combobox to JFrame
      text.setLocation(100,100);
      frame.add(text);
      frame.add(button);

      //set default close operation for JFrame 
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      //set JFrame ssize 
      frame.setSize(250,250);  

      //make JFrame visible. So we can see it 
      frame.setVisible(true);  

   }  
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read as you are over-doing it with white space. Please edit your code to make it easier on us to be able to help you.

Comment: And why are you adding a JPanel to a JComboBox? This is not correct usage of a JComboBox. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Heck if I must fix your code myself....

Comment: im trying to have text to the left side of the JComboBox saying something like "select shape"

Comment: That's not how this is done. Please take some time and effort to describe ***exactly*** what you're trying to do. You're still leaving way too much unsaid. Or better yet, show a picture of what your desired result should be.

Comment: okay. As you can see I am trying to create a drop down menu with text to the left side essentially 'labelling' it, for example "Select shape". I've tried using a JLabel but it doesn't show anything. I also want to add a label to the text field I have created. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep,  you've got a good answer, 1+ to him. Other suggestions: don't set the size of the JFrame and avoid over-use of FlowLayout. Consider using BoxLayout if you want to stack components one on top of the other, and consider packing your JFrame once you've added everything to it and before calling `setVisible(true)`. And please work on posting easier to read code to this site. No sense in making it harder than it has to be to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code will produce more or less what you expect.

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
{
    //Create array containing shapes
    String[] shapes ={"(no shape selected)","Circle","Equilateral Triangle","Square"};

    //Use combobox to create drop down menu
    JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox(shapes);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Select shape:");
    panel1.add(label1);
    panel1.add(comboBox);

    JButton button = new JButton("GO");
    JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    //Create a JFrame that will be use to put JComboBox into it
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Area Calculator Window");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //set layout
    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.add(text);
    frame.add(button);
    //set default close operation for JFrame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //set JFrame ssize
    frame.setSize(250,250);

    //make JFrame visible. So we can see it
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```